# The Godfather: 2001 vs 2008 edition

Tags: alternate-version, the-godfather

What are the differences between both editions except for the colors? Any difference in scenes (additional/removed/replaced scenes)?

IMDb says 175 minutes, the Blu-ray info says 177..

So, are there any differences between the original first edition (2001) and the Coppola restoration (2008)?